# Azure CosmosDB Emulator not responding to call from MacOS

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to run the CosmosDB Emulator on a Mac. Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-mac-or-linux), I set up everything on a Windows VM and exported the certificate and saved it in my local Keychain. However, whenever I try to get the table from the emulator via the line

`const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({
        id: databaseId
    });`

I get stuck with no response. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try connecting to a live instance of a Cosmos DB account. If that works then something is wrong with your setup for the emulator. Try going over each step again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of this problem is that the windows firewall blocks the traffic.

By default, the windows firewall is turned on and it will block all un-recognized inbound traffic. To solve this, you may [create an Inbound Port Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule) or [turn off it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028544/windows-10-turn-windows-defender-firewall-on-or-off).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That was half the issue. The other half was to change the VM's network from NAT to Bridged Adapter. After that I had to play around with the time on the VM to ensure the tokens weren't invalid.